# How do I run an iterative 2D convolution for each slice of a tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I'm working on a machine learning project with convolutional neural networks using TF/Keras in Python, and my goal is to split up an image up into patches, run a convolution on each one separately, and then put it back together.

What I can't figure out how to do is **run a convolution for each slice of a 3D array.**

For example, if I have a tensor of size `(500,100,100)` I want to do a separate convolution for all 500 slices of size `(100 x 100)`. I'm implementing this within a custom Keras layer and want these to be trainable weights I've tried a few different things:

1. Using `map.fn()` to run a convolution for each slice of the array

   - This doesn't seem to attach weights to each layer separately.
2. Using the `DepthwiseConv2D` layer:

   - This works well for the first call of the layer, but fails when I call the layer the second time with more filters because it wants to perform the `depthwise` convolution on each of the previous filtered layers
   - This, of course isn't what I want because I want one convolution for each of the previous sets of filters from the previous layer.

Any ideas are appreciated, as I'm truly stuck here. Thank you!

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem exactly, however if you have a tensor with shape (500,100,100) and want to feed some subset of this tensor, to separate conv2d layers at the same time, you may do this by defining conv2d layers in the same level. For example, if you want to feed the tensor to 5 separate conv2d layer, you should create 5 branch of the layer which its output is (500,100,100) to 5 lambda layers which extract patches of shape (100,100,100) and connect each of them to a separate conv2d layer, then concat their outputs.

Comment: @Kaveh Thanks for the response! That makes sense, but I'm not totally sure how to implement this. I tried using map.fn() to apply the lambda function each time: `out = tf.map_fn(Lambda(lambda x: self.Conv2Dee(x)),img)` where "img" is my stack of tensors and "Conv2Dee" is the custom convolution function I wrote, but I get the following error: `The following Variables were created within a Lambda layer (lambda)
    but are not tracked by said layer:
    The layer cannot safely ensure proper Variable reuse across multiple
    calls, and consquently this behavior is disallowed for safety...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a tensor with shape `(500,100,100)` and want to feed some subset of this tensor, to separate `conv2d` layers at the same time, you may do this by defining `conv2d` layers in the same level. You should first define `Lambda` layers to split input, then feed their output to `Conv2D` layers, then `concatenate` them.

Let's take a tensor with shape `(100,28,28,1)` as an example, that we want to split it into 2 subset tensor and apply `conv2d` layers on each subset separately:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D, Input, concatenate, Lambda
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

# define a sample dataset
x = tf.random.uniform((100, 28, 28, 1))
y = tf.random.uniform((100, 1), dtype=tf.int32, minval=0, maxval=9)
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y))
ds = ds.batch(16)

def create_nn_model():
    input = Input(shape=(28,28,1))
    b1 = Lambda(lambda a: a[:,:14,:,:], name="first_slice")(input)
    b2 = Lambda(lambda a: a[:,14:,:,:], name="second_slice")(input)
    d1 = Conv2D(64, 2, padding='same', activation='relu', name="conv1_first_slice")(b1)
    d2 = Conv2D(64, 2, padding='same', activation='relu', name="conv2_second_slice")(b2)
    x =  concatenate([d1,d2], axis=1)
    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
    out = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)
    model = Model(input, out)
    model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

model = create_nn_model()
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes=True)
```

Here is the plotted model architecture:

[image: plotted_model]

Comment: thank you this is really helpful! One question -- is there any way to scale this? If, for example, I want to run one hundred different separate convolutions, can I do this without having to manually define 100 Conv2D layers?

Comment: Yes. you can define layers within a loop ;-)